# Взаимодействие floating action button и viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

У меня есть `TabLayout` c 2 вкладками и `ViewPager`. В каждую вкладку надо установить свои функции `FloatingActionButton` (в одном фрагменте она выполняет одну функцию, в другом фрагменте другую). Но нужно, чтобы при использовании `ViewPager` кнопка оставалась на своем месте с изменением иконки и слушателя. Можно ли как-то это реализовать? (пример такой функции есть в telegram x, но приложение не разбирается)

Answer (score 2):

1. `FloatingActionButton` поместите в активити, на одном уровне в разметке с ViewPager.
2. Повесьте на `ViewPager` слушатель переключения страниц.
3. В слушателе в зависимсоти от страницы вешайте нужный слушатель на `FloatingActionButton` и меняйте ему иконку

Comment: TabLayout находится во фрагменте bottom navigation view.

Comment: Что это меняет? В общем не важно что где находится. Просто поместите ФАБ поверх Пейджера и реагируйте на смену страниц/табов.

Comment: слушатель на viewpager повесил, но как действовать дальше не понимаю

Comment: Теперь просто в слушателе меняйте иконку и слушатель нажатий на FAB

Comment: mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
mFab.setIcon(R.drawable.plus); не получается даже иконку сменить. Не распознает метод setIcon

Comment: Вот метод: setImageResource

Comment: А если мне нужен Floating Action Menu (https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) в одном фрагменте, а в другом простой Floating Action Button?

Comment: @3Jlou4uTep, поместите оба в разметку и меняйте им видимость

Comment: сделал, тогда выходит очень грубо. Просто один fab резко заменяется другим fab, хотя нужно, чтобы с самим fab ничего не происходило, но менялась только иконка и функционал.

Comment: @3Jlou4uTep, попробуйте тогда Floating Action Menu настроить так, чтобы он как обычный выглядел/работал